# Javax ClientBuilder post() removes file before sending to web service

Tags: java, web-services, rest, file-upload, playframework

I'm trying to send temporary file to RESTful web service. I'm using the following function to do this:

```
private static String nlpFileUpload(String filePath) throws IOException {
    // Check is file exists
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if(!file.isFile()) {
        throw new FileNotFoundException();
    }

    // Upload file to web service
    return ClientBuilder.newClient()
        .target(nlprestURL + "upload")
        .request()
        .post(
                Entity.entity(file, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM)
        ).readEntity(String.class);
}
```

The problem is, in method `.post()` the file is sometimes removed from disk and FileNotFound exception is returned:

```
[ERROR] [04/18/2016 19:04:35.945] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [TaskInvocation] java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/multipartBody3655134388737861177asTemporaryFile (No such file or directory)
javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/multipartBody3655134388737861177asTemporaryFile (No such file or directory)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:287)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:255)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:684)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:681)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:437)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:343)
at pl.edu.pwr.services.serel.SerelServiceRs.nlpFileUpload(SerelServiceRs.java:97)
at pl.edu.pwr.services.serel.SerelServiceRs.processFile(SerelServiceRs.java:181)
at jobs.ProcessDocuments.run(ProcessDocuments.java:54)
at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:41)
at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/multipartBody3655134388737861177asTemporaryFile (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:115)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.FileProvider.writeTo(FileProvider.java:67)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:265)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:250)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:162)
at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1130)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRequest.writeEntity(ClientRequest.java:502)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:388)
at org.glassfish.jersey.client.internal.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:285)
... 19 more
```

But this exception does not appears always. While debugging I've found out that sometimes the file is sent to service correctly, but in other time above exception appears.
I don't know what is wrong here. The service is able to read files as `MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM` but I think the problem is on the client side. Why `.post()` method removes my file before sending it to web service?

I'm using Play framework 2.3.9 in my application. `nlpFileUpload(String filePath)` function is called by Akka scheduler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with play temporary files is that they are deleted when they are garbaged collected. Temporary files are created when a file is uploaded by a client and handled as `MultipartFormData`. That must be why your code sometimes works.

To solve this, you can try to keep a reference to this file so it's not cleaned up by the garbage collector. You can start by changing the definition of your function to use this reference:

```
static String nlpFileUpload(File file) throws IOException
```

Comment: I called Garbage Collector by System.gc() and indeed my temporary file was deleted. I've solved this problem by saving content to a regular file. Still don't know why the temporary file was removed exactly in `.post()` method.